# How to read a plist of array and dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm following the apple example project TVAnimationsGestures but applying it to one of my own projects. I need to load data from a plist into my classes but i cant seem to figure out how to do it in swift. Here is an image of the plist in trying to read.

[image]

The example project reads the plist using this method

```
- (NSArray *)plays {

if (_plays == nil) {

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PlaysAndQuotations" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSArray *playDictionariesArray = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    _plays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[playDictionariesArray count]];

    for (NSDictionary *playDictionary in playDictionariesArray) {

        APLPlay *play = [[APLPlay alloc] init];
        play.name = playDictionary[@"playName"];

        NSArray *quotationDictionaries = playDictionary[@"quotations"];
        NSMutableArray *quotations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[quotationDictionaries count]];

        for (NSDictionary *quotationDictionary in quotationDictionaries) {

            APLQuotation *quotation = [[APLQuotation alloc] init];
            [quotation setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:quotationDictionary];

            [quotations addObject:quotation];
        }
        play.quotations = quotations;

        [_plays addObject:play];
    }
}

return _plays;
```

}

I've looked around and managed to get most of it to not display any errors but I don't think it's done properly because there's a lot of casting. Here's how far I've got:

```
    func loadFoodCategoryData() ->[Any] {
    // foodCategoryData is declared outside the function
    if foodCategoryData == nil {

        var url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Items", withExtension: "plist")!
        var categoryDictionaryArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) as! [[String:AnyObject!]]
        foodCategoryData = Array()

        for foodDictionary:Dictionary in categoryDictionaryArray {

            var foodCat = FoodCategories()
            foodCat.foodCategoryName = foodDictionary["categoryName"] as! String

            var foodItemsDict = foodDictionary["items"]
            var foodItemsArray = [AnyObject]()

            for foodItems in foodDictionary {

                var foodItem:FoodItems = FoodItems()
                foodItem.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(foodItems as! Dictionary)

                foodItemsArray.append(foodItem)

            }
        }
    }

    return foodCategoryData
}
```

Anyone have any better and more efficient ways to load this plist into my classes?

Comment: Do you declare `foodCategoryData` outside of the function? What do you declare it as?

Comment: Yes, it's a variable outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

lazy initialized variables have a specific syntax in Swift. The equivalent to the ObjC code is (body simplified)

```
  lazy var plays : [AnyObject] = {
    var foodCategoryData = [AnyObject]()
    // do things
    foodCategoryData.append("something")
    return foodCategoryData
  }()
```

The down-casting from AnyObject is a pain but necessary

**Edit**

Your code is quite close. Try this (untested)

```
lazy var foodCategoryData : [AnyObject] = {

  let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Items", withExtension: "plist")!
  var categoryDictionaryArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) as! [[String:AnyObject!]]
  var foodItemsArray = [FoodItems]()

  for foodDictionary in categoryDictionaryArray {

    var foodCat = FoodCategories()
    foodCat.foodCategoryName = foodDictionary["categoryName"] as! String

    var foodItemsDict = foodDictionary["items"] as! [String:AnyObject]


    for foodItems in foodDictionary {

      var foodItem:FoodItems = FoodItems()
      foodItem.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(foodItems as! Dictionary)

      foodItemsArray.append(foodItem)

    }
  }
  return foodItemsArray
 }()
```

Comment: I understand that part. What I don't understand is how to pull the data from my plist and set the values into my custom classses.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the most part. I get a warning at 
"foodItem.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(foodItems as! Dictionary)" it says "casting from (String,implicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AnyObject>) to unrelated type Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> always fails"